# How do I clear an element inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a span element

```
<span>Test</span>
```

inside an iframe.

How do I clear that element using vanilla javascript? Remove the html/text inside it so it becomes

```
<span></span>
```

NOTE: THE SPAN IS INSIDE AN IFRAME

Here's my code:

```
var clearElement = function (fid) {
    document.querySelector(fid).innerHTML = "";
};
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.clearElement(fid);
```

Comment: so the function is in the iframe? That is what you are calling.

Comment: `document.querySelector` is going to run in the context of your main document, NOT the document inside the frame.

Comment: how do you make it run inside the context of the iframe?

Comment: What's the value of `fid`? Is `clearElement` function placed within the iframe document? The code looks like it was.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is trying to somehow call a function inside of the iframe which is not you have. First the iframe needs to be in the same domain. Second, you need to use the DOM of the iframe, not the current window

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId'); 
//var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var content = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
content.getElementById("theId").innerHTML = "";
```

Now if the span does not have an id, than we need more context on how to select the span. `querySelector("span")` will get the first span.